# Colons in fieldsmanes on Field List (fl) breaks solr query

Tags: solr

I have field names with colons in, such as "rdf:type", when I use these in the field list of a query (i.e. included in the fields I want to return ) I either get an error it they get completely ignored.

This worked fine in 1.4 Solr but doesn't work in 5.5 or 6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Solr4.0 the fieldlist has got much more complicated.

To pass in any fieldname use this syntax:

```
field(rdf:type),field(another:strange:field),id
```

Unfortunately these extended names will also be used in the returned data for example:

```
"field(id)":"uuid:001edfdd-b48c-41a0-a136-eed52f6df156",
```

so you may have to change how you deal with the results too.

For more details see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2444